# Compile C only with const

Tags: c, constants

I need to generate a datafile, but i do not know how. I did this, years ago, a .c file, wiht only const's, like this, and I compiled and got what I Need:

```
const unsigned int icone1[576] = {
0xF7FE,0xF7FE,0xFFFE,0xFFBE,0xFFBF,0xFFDF,0xFFDF,0xF7DF,0xF7FF,0xEFFF,0xEFFE,0xF7FE,0xFFDE}
const unsigned int icone2[576] = {
0xF7FE,0xF7FE,0xFFFE,0xFFBE,0xFFBF,0xFFDF,0xFFDF,0xF7DF,0xF7FF,0xEFFF,0xEFFE,0xF7FE,0xFFDE}
```

But forgot, and i do not know how to compiled. Both, gcc and borland, if compiled only with -c, they put "0000" between data generated, like below:

```
00000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD
00000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD
00000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD
00000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD
00000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD
00000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD0000FFDD
```

Someone know how to do this?

Comment: What does that observation mean? What did you expect? What did you get? You'll have to use these via `extern`, though you should also ask yourself if storing these in global constants a good idea.

Comment: Well, how big is `int` on your system? Those simply look like leading zeros. Perhaps you want `uint16_t` instead of `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide the length of each item. 
In your example, it seems you want them to be 16bit.

Use a standard sized integer may be helpful, like this:

```
const uint16_t icone1[576] = { 0xF7FE, 0xF7FE, ...
```

Have a try. 
And be aware it also depends on your compiler and compiler options.